# Access Button Primary Color In React

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, jss

I am trying to provide overrides in the theme for buttons that are contained, primary and hovered. I tried this but it doesn't work

**CODESANDBOX LINK**  [CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-7di2c?file=/theme/overrides/MuiButton.js)

**theme/overrides/MuiButton.js**

```
import palette from '../palette';

export default {
  contained: {
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    '&.primary': {
      '&:hover': {
        backgroundColor: palette.primary.dark,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

**theme/overrides/index.js**

```
import MuiButton from "./MuiButton";

export default {
  MuiButton
};
```

**theme/index.js**

```
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core";

import palette from "./palette";
import typography from "./typography";
import overrides from "./overrides";

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette,
  typography,
  overrides,
  zIndex: {
    appBar: 1200,
    drawer: 1100
  }
});

export default theme;
```

Comment: You don't have SCSS syntax in CSS...

Comment: @DennisVash He is using Material Ui so it doesn't matter if he installed sass or not.

Comment: And who said you have scss in material UI styling? Do you have a source? - NVM there is an example here: https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#nesting-selectors, seems like MUI usess JSS as a source

Comment: @DennisVash. I'm using JSS

Comment: Please show how you are trying to leverage these styles. Ideally, include a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) demonstrating your problem.

Comment: @RyanCogswell. Here it is https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-7di2c?file=/theme/overrides/MuiButton.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best resource for determining how to appropriately override the default styles in your theme, is to look at how the default styles are defined.

From https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.0/packages/material-ui/src/Button/Button.js#L138:

```
  containedPrimary: {
    color: theme.palette.primary.contrastText,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.dark,
      // Reset on touch devices, it doesn't add specificity
      '@media (hover: none)': {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
      },
    },
  },
```

Translating this approach to the code in your question would look like this:

```
import palette from '../palette';

export default {
  containedPrimary: {
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: palette.primary.dark,
    },
  },
};
```

[image: Edit Material demo]

Comment: How about on the `success` button? Pls check this https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-lozwd?file=/demo.js

Comment: @Joseph For the success button in your sandbox, put the `className` on the Button instead of the `Link`: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-kd56r?file=/demo.js. I've also combined the `Link` with the `Button` via the `component` prop.